# Pre-render JQM pages in the background

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile web app built with jQuery Mobile. It is using a multi-page template, with most of the content being created dynamically with javascript. The first time the app is loaded it shows a splash screen and then sends the user to an "index" page. From there the user can navigate to different parts of the app via # links. Each page's content is created dynamically with javascript and then inserted into the DOM on the "pageshow" event.

This works very well with one little problem that I haven't been able to solve. The first time a page is loaded it takes several seconds for the content to be generated and inserted into the DOM. Subsequent loads are fine since the previously rendered content is already in the DOM and is only replaced if there is new data. What I want to do is pre-render each page's DOM so that there is no noticeable delay when a page is loaded for the first time. I can achieve this by calling $.mobile.changePage() on each page. The problem is that I want this to be done in the background without the pages or any page transitions being shown to the user. Is there any way to do this?

P.S.: Worst-case scenario, I'd just keep the splash screen on top of everything while the pages are pre-rendered, but I can't even do this since JQM does the transition and changes the page whenever I call $.mobile.changePage().

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is use the `$.mobile.loadPage`.  In the example below I show how to initialize a single page by hash URL upon the showing of #one.  You could list out all of them if you wanted or create a fancy script to find all the `[data-role]` elements that do not have a class of `ui-page`, grab it's ID, and call a load on in the same way I have here.

```
    $("#one").live("pageshow",function(){
        $.mobile.loadPage("#two");
    });
```

You can see the example in action on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgliser/ftd2H/8/)..

Comment: Maybe it's not clear in the question. I'm creating the contents of each page dynamically on `pageshow`. For this reason I can't call loadPage('#two') as it won't trigger a `pageshow`. Maybe I'm missing something and there's another event that I can bind to when using `loadPage()`. But even if this is the case the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) say that `loadPage()` loads the content of an **external** page. Not sure how the jsFiddle demonstrates a solution since #two already has all the jqm markup and doesn't need to be enhanced or inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I'll give it a go with my app and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I know that it says that you can only use it on external pages, but as I was playing around with it on jsfiddle, I was able to watch it apply the class of ui-page to the div with the id of "two". A page that has not been initialized will not have that class. So, despite what they may have stated in the docs, the URL resolver knows what to do in this case.

Comment: Are you saying that you are creating and transitioning to a page and THEN filling in the content?

Comment: Also, I dont know if you're using JSON for your data when creating the pages, but you might find one of my recent blog posts useful.  http://roughlybrilliant.com/how_to_use_jquery_templates_and_json_apis_with_jquery_mobile

Comment: 1. I am pretty sure that even when you remove the call to `pageLoad('#two')`, it would still apply the class of ui-page simply because the div has data-role="page" and JQM will automatically enhance it.

Comment: 2. Yes, I am creating a page dynamically. Then, on `pageshow` of that page generating the content and enhancing it using `.trigger('refresh')`, `.listview()`, etc. as appropriate. I want to be able to generate the content and pre-render it without actually having to show the page. Problem is I can't call the enhance methods, before `pageshow` due to the way jqm works. I think I can't explain this very well. Will try to put some code up later.

Comment: 3. Thanks. Looks interesting, will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question since I was looking into somewhat the same issue. What I ended up with is a _preloadPages() function in my project basically instantiating the page widgets which normally are done internally. Since this is not documented please keep in mind this can break anytime when upgrading JQM.

To control which pages to preload and which not I've introduced a class 'preload' which I place on the page containers I want to preload. This _preloadPages() function I call during splash screen and to not stress the initialization of my app to much the preloading is done in a 300ms interval. Still playing with these numbers though.

```
function _preloadPages()
{
    // Execute the page() widget call on all pages that haven't yet been initialized, we do this
    // to prevent a slight delay when initially loading a page
    //
    var $pages      = $( "[data-role='page'].preload:not(.ui-page)" )
    ,   index       = 0
    ,   pageCount   = $pages.length
    ;

    var preloadTimer = setInterval( function()
    {
        var page    = $pages[ index ]
        ,   $page   = $( page )
        ;

        $page.page();

        index++;

        if ( index === pageCount )
        {
            clearTimeout( preloadTimer );
        }
    }, 300 );
}
```